# MySQL: trying to find to correct MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the two following tables' schema:
`Users(first_name,last_name,age,gender)`
`Friends(friend_one,friend_two)`

where `first_name` is a key in `Users` and the values in 'Friends' table (`friend_one` and `friend_two`) are actually `first_name`'s taken from the 'Users' table. (meaning referential integrity holds between `Users(first_name)` and `Friends(friend_one,friend_two)`.

I'm trying to get the "Ten most popular friends", meaning the 10 users with the most friends, with the right MySQL query.
My first attempt at this was:

```
SELECT first_name,COUNT(first_name) 
FROM users,friends
WHERE first_name=friend_one OR first_name=friend_two
GROUP BY first_name;
```

So first, I'm not sure if this is the right query, and the more obvious problem is that it won't produce the **top 10**.
I know that SQL has the keyword `TOP`, but I'm using MySQL.
Is the above query correct? if not, why, and how can I get the top 10?

Comment: Just curious what will happen if you have two users named *John*

Comment: `first_name` is a key.

Comment: One way is with UNION (reversing the columns in the second query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would write your version of the query:

```
SELECT u.first_name, COUNT(first_name) as NumFriends
FROM users u join
     friends f
     on u.first_name = f.friend_one OR u.first_name = f.friend_two
GROUP BY u.first_name
ORDER BY NumFriends
LIMIT 10;
```

This will work if `friends` is a symmetric relationship with only one row between any two friends.  If friends can have multiple rows (so person1 can friend person2 and vice versa), then this may overcount the number.  It is not clear if that is possible.

Note that I "fixed" the query to use proper `join` syntax, added table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names, and the `order by` and `limit`clauses.

Comment: friends cannot have multiple rows. Thanks. I'll give that a try!

Comment: and what's the difference between using 'join' and not using it?

Comment: @so.very.tired . . . The implicit `join` syntax was enhanced with the explicit `join` syntax in 1992.  Although still allowed, the explicit joins are generally considered more readable (because the join conditions are right next to the tables being joins) and more powerful (because it allows outer joins).  As for performance, they should be very similar, although optimizers could theoretically come up with different plans.  (The latter is more likely in databases that have more powerful optimizers, such as SQL Server and Oracle.)